# Do I need to create a database table or are there already tools on offer?

Tags: views, database, theming

Pretty new to drupal, I'm afraid!

I have a excel table of survey results which I need to display certain cells from on a drupal page. I was thinking of creating a new table in my drupal database and then using PHP to link to it. I can't seem to create this table and what I've read suggests that this isn't a good way to go about it.

Does anyone know a better tool within drupal for this? Views or creating a custom module?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Do you need only to *display* the data or you need to update it as well?

Comment: I only need to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need some additional styling or processing of data, the easiest way is to [Embed a spreadsheet using Google Docs](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244). You don't need any module for that.

If you need to have that data in Drupal as well, then check out [Feeds Excel](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_excel) or [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1197306) on drupal.org. The latter relies on the [PHP Excel reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) class which you should use in your custom module.